# Is a @user notified in a comment if their @name is added in an edit to that comment?

Tags: support, comments, notifications, comment-replies, comment-edits

If I add the comment:

> Why isn't this question clear?

to a post, but forgot to notify the user to whom I am replying, does editing my comment to:

> Why isn't this question clear? @User

– notify that user?  Or do I have add a completely new comment (and delete the old one) for them to be notified?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that edits to comments do re-notify pinged users.  EDIT: I think I misinterpretted your question.  You cannot ping users from posts (unless they already receive notifications, e.g. the OP gets a notification for new answers).  But if you edit a comment I think they get re-notified.

Comment: Oh, okay @ryanyuyu, if (and once) you're sure, post that as an answer :).

Comment: I feel like I had actually read something that said they _did_ notify the user, so long as you did not originally have a ping and just change the username. Edit: Let's test this, I'll edit in @ryanyuyu

Comment: @Kendra sorry wasn't paying attention.  I just cleared my notifications.  Re-edit please?  Oh wait.  I guess that means it worked.  It's in my notification box.

Comment: Let's double check. (Edited: @ryanyuyu)

Comment: Found a couple sources on MSE: [This MSE dupe of your question,](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197393/do-users-get-notifications-when-was-edited-in) and [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) both address this.

Comment: Let's double check. (Edited: @Kendra)

Comment: Should this question stay here @Kendra?

Comment: Won't hurt anything to leave this here. If nothing else, someone else looking for the answer can stumble upon this one. :)

Comment: On MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197393/do-users-get-notifications-when-was-edited-in

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, the user is probably notified.  Retroactively editing an existing comment to ping a user will usually notify the user.  Thanks to [Kendra's MSE hunting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317021/is-a-user-notified-in-a-comment-if-their-name-is-added-in-an-edit-to-that-comm?noredirect=1#comment309483_317021), the relevant portion of [How do comment replies work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) explains:

> **Can I change who gets notified after the comment is posted?**
>
> When editing a comment within its limited editing period, if you change or add @name, the [notification may or may not reach the new recipient](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40989/will-edited-comments-reach-addressees/74781#74781) depending on timing.

In my experience, I am re-notified when users edit comments they have previously pinged me in.  And our testing in these comments notified me after being edited in retroactively.

Comment: Hm. Based on the excerpt, potentially by changing the tagname you can ping multiple people within a short window of time then?

Comment: Anyone get any pings from me?

Comment: @BillWoodger [yes](http://i.imgur.com/cuWoC3g.png).  I'm guessing you edited me in/out of the comment?

Comment: Not quite. It wouldn't let me ping you, as you are the answerer. I pinged the other two... but perhaps didn't work :-)

Comment: @BillWoodger that makes actually sense.  I kinda forgot that these were comments on my post.

Comment: He he, nice and vague :) "The other two". If anyone pinged me, I didn't get notified.

Comment: @Gimby I think the short is, if my final edit leaves no at-to-user, there's no ping at all, so on this *extensive testing*, you can't ping multiple users by editing a comment. There may be a short time before the edit that the a user is actually pinged if they are online, but after that I think the message is gone from their inbox, like a deleted comment.