# Is a @user notified even if they haven't commented on that question?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

Recently I was commenting on a question in a tag I frequent and the OP added a comment pinging a high rep user in the tag asking for their help specifically. By 'pinging' I mean something like

> @HighRepUser have you come across something like this before? Do you know how to solve it?

Does that actually notify the person if they hadn't previously commented on the question? My gut instinct is no, but that's just because I haven't seen it done before, usually users talk to other commenters in the comments.

Comment: If HighRepUser didn't comment on the post, edit the post and /or didn't dupe hammer the post they won't get notified.  See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: and if you only have 2 pings now and only on this post I have proven my point ...

Comment: @rene thank you! I do only have 2 pings now, so that proves your point. The linked meta question was helpful, should I close this question since it is effectively a cross site duplicate of that one?

Comment: Closed questions with no answers tend to get deleted quickly, and then next time someone has this question again, they won't find in on this site when they search.

Comment: Highly related but not quite a dupe: [Is a `@user` notified in a comment if their `@name` is added in an edit to that comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317021/is-a-user-notified-in-a-comment-if-their-name-is-added-in-an-edit-to-that-comm)

Comment: This kind of feature would inundate high-rep users. Some users would receive hundreds or thousands of pings a day. Stack Overflow is specifically built to prevent this, hence the lack of any kind of messaging feature that allows you to initiate direct conversation with a user. You can only directly communicate with a user by commenting *below* them on a post where they have already contributed.

Comment: If this feature exit, every day Jon Skeet might receive more than  million notifications per month.

Comment: If you think about it, it wouldn't even be possible to implement such a feature as usernames are not unique. [Even Jon Skeet is non-unique!](https://stackoverflow.com/users?search=jon+skeet)

Comment: @DidierL So what happens if both the real and the fake Skeet comments and I mention them?

Comment: @totymedli the [JonSkeet that commented most recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/158100) is pinged.

Comment: No one has mentioned this yet, but while the system doesn't support pinging arbitrary people, it's possible the OP knew/suspected that HighRepUser follows those specific tags, and hadn't read the question yet.  There's nothing wrong in calling out to a user, in the hopes they'll read your comment and respond.  There's just no system support for it.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein yes, I suspect that was the original intent, it's a smallish tag with a few 'regulars' who follow the tag and help with a lot of the questions.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson _"every day"_ ... _"per month"_ .. :'D

Answer (score 49, accepted):

No, there aren't instant messaging features to <s>harass</s> provoke interest from certain users to a post.

Users can only be @-replied when:

- they have commented earlier on the post
- they have edited the post
- they have dupe-hammered the question
- set a bounty on the question.

See the full details in [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Due to these restrictions you totally missed my comment:

> [image: a test comment]

which makes me sad due to the lack of response ...

Comment: Awww.... sadflower.jpg

Comment: What's that "timeline" button in the screenshot? Why don't I have it?

Comment: There's a timeline button for high rep users? I thought you had to manipulate urls to get to the timeline!

Comment: I always wondered why I never got any response from people I incorrectly tagged.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier, South Park rules! :)

Comment: @Sweeper It's a [userscript](https://github.com/Tunaki/stackoverflow-userscripts), does nothing else but edit the URL and create a button

Comment: @LW001: ...or at least one of the many user scripts floating around that do pretty much the same thing. [Here's mine](https://gist.github.com/vyznev/1f558af47f205d85f1f3862060cd1628), for example.